# How to fix Intent.getAction() error in services on Android

Tags: java, android, android-service

In my application i want use one **Service** for record device screen and this name is `RecorderService` !

I write below codes, but in some devices when running **service** show ForceClose error and application has stopped !

**My Service codes:**

```
public class RecorderService extends Service {
    private static final SparseIntArray ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();
    private int WIDTH, HEIGHT, FPS, DENSITY_DPI;
    private int BITRATE;
    private boolean isBound = false;
    private String audioRecSource;
    private String SAVEPATH, videoName;
    private AudioManager mAudioManager;
    private FloatingControlService floatingControlService;

    static {
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 0);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 90);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 180);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 270);
    }

    private int screenOrientation;
    private String saveLocation;

    private boolean isRecording;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message message) {
            Toast.makeText(RecorderService.this, "Service stoped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

    private Intent data;
    private int result;

    private WindowManager window;
    private MediaProjection mMediaProjection;
    private VirtualDisplay mVirtualDisplay;
    private MediaProjectionCallback mMediaProjectionCallback;
    private MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder;

    //Service connection to manage the connection state between this service and the bounded service
    private ServiceConnection serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            //Get the service instance
            FloatingControlService.ServiceBinder binder = (FloatingControlService.ServiceBinder) service;
            floatingControlService = binder.getService();
            isBound = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            floatingControlService = null;
            isBound = false;
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        videoName = GoodPrefs.getInstance().getString(ConstKeys.TEST_NAME, "Testady");
        //return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        //Find the action to perform from intent
        switch (Objects.requireNonNull(intent.getAction())) {
            case ConstKeys.SCREEN_RECORDING_START:
                if (!isRecording) {
                    screenOrientation = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
                    data = intent.getParcelableExtra(ConstKeys.RECORDER_INTENT_DATA);
                    result = intent.getIntExtra(ConstKeys.RECORDER_INTENT_RESULT, Activity.RESULT_OK);

                    getValues();

                    startRecording();

                    openTestApp();

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Service has running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
            case ConstKeys.SCREEN_RECORDING_PAUSE:
                break;
            case ConstKeys.SCREEN_RECORDING_RESUME:
                break;
            case ConstKeys.SCREEN_RECORDING_STOP:
                stopRecording();
                break;
        }

        return START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

**logcat error** (get this error from firebase):

```
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Intent.getAction()' on a null object reference
com.app.app.services.RecorderService.onStartCommand (RecorderService.java:126)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs (ActivityThread.java:3028)
android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200 (ActivityThread.java:157)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1454)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:148)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5525)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:730)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:620)
```

Show me error for this error : `switch (Objects.requireNonNull(intent.getAction()))`

**I start service with this codes:**

```
Intent recorderService = new Intent(this, RecorderService.class);
    recorderService.setAction(ConstKeys.SCREEN_RECORDING_START);
    recorderService.putExtra(ConstKeys.RECORDER_INTENT_DATA, data);
    recorderService.putExtra(ConstKeys.RECORDER_INTENT_RESULT, resultCode);
    startService(recorderService);
    finish();
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: `NullPointerException`

Comment: It is strange that the intent parameter is null. Indeed. Anyhow.. you could do a check `if (intent==null) { Toast ( ... sorry intent is null); stopSelf(); return;}`. All to be sure that your app does not crash.

Comment: @blackapps, thanks for send code but where use this? can you send to me code with my above codes?

Comment: Isnt it clear to you which statement causes the exception? If not then you should have told that. If yes well then before you execute that statement. Before you use the intent parameter.

Comment: @blackapps, really don't know :( can you help me?

Comment: In your logcat there is the error on `java.lang.String android.content.Intent.getAction()' on a null object refere..`. Now you can easily find where you call `getAction()`. You should not have done that as  `intent` in `intent.getAction()` is `null`.